# how to print row in CVS file in one line?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a CSV file that contains two columns and I want to print the contents of the second column.

For example: **(from this)**

```
for row in file1:
    print(row[1])
```

**to this:**

```
print([row[1] for row in file1])
```

The problem is that it doesn't print anything. Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: Check the documentation for this
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.reader

Comment: It seems like your question provides an example of code that _works_ and the second example _does not work_ but it's not clear from your question. Is your question about the difference between the two examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
[print(row[1]) for row in file1]
```

`Edit:`

To avoid printing first line (which is mostly header) do

```
next(file1)
[print(row[1]) for row in file1]
```

Comment: it works exactly as I want. thank you very much, but could you please explain the idea of the bracket before print   ----[print(row[1])]---.

Comment: the bracket is used as list comprehension.  As you did in your code in question, print should be inside the loop. You can find more on https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

Solution without using any libraries

```
with open('file.txt') as file1:
  print([x.split(",")[1] for x in file1.read().split("\n")])
```

More elegant output

```
with open('file.txt') as file1:
  print("\n".join([x.split(",")[1] for x in file1.read().split("\n")]))
```

Comment: Bypassing the CSV parsing library doesn't necessarily answer the question. It definitely introduces problems parsing files that follow the CSV format. It's not only about comma-separation.